# navbar-collapse button not working for some views

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

`navbar-collapse` **button** not working for some views.

- It works for **index.html** and **blogs.html**
- It does not work for **blog1.html**

I suspect it has to do something with path lookups.

Every view inside `main/views` works correctly.

But every view inside `main/views/blogs/` does not work.

I have my `node.js` source setup as:

```
main
main/public/index.html
main/views/blogs.html
main/views/blogs/blog1.html
main/public/css/bootstrap.min.css
main/public/css/custom.css
```

**node app.js**

```
app.get('/blogs', function (req, res) {
  res.render('blogs.html',
  { title : '' }
  )
})

app.get('/blogs/:id', function (req, res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  res.render('blogs/' + id + '.html',
  { title : '' }
  )
});
```

**Head element blogs.html**

```
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Head element blog1.html**

```
  <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Navbar element blogs.html**

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"  style="font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold'"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">TymeIt<small></small></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul style="font-family:futura;font-size:18px" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/blogs">Blogs</a></li>
              <li><a href="/videos">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
     </div>
    </div>
```

**Navbar element blog1.html**

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style="font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT Bold'"><img id="logo" src="/img/logo.png">TymeIt<small></small></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
           <ul style="font-family:futura;font-size:18px" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/blogs">Blogs</a></li>
              <li><a href="/videos">Videos</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact" class="page-scroll">Contact</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/holder.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Can you help me resolve this?

Comment: Which is the value of the id ?

Comment: App.js is getting a suposed id param

Comment: Im not sure but.. dot dot slash css in the head of blog1.html

Comment: is it just `navbar-collapse` or it's the not importing bootstrap at all?

Comment: You don't have jQuery and Bootstrap JS. Then this is the problem. Try to import jQuery first and then Bootstrap JS, and it will start to work.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh Thank you so much. My path to js for blog1 was broken. If you put it as an answer, I ll accept.